# Back button on Azure app is not doing anything

Tags: azure-active-directory

I created an azure app, and when generating an authorize URL it leads me to login page which does have a Back button, but clicking on it does nothing except button disappearing.

[image]

If I progress into permission part the Cancel button there does redirect me back to my URL.
How can I make this Back button work? I couldn't find anything there.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={myclientid}&scope=User.Read+Calendars.ReadWrite+offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri={my_redirect_url}&state=1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: The `back` button allows you to re-select the account to sign in if there are multiple accounts.

- If there are multiple accounts logged in the browser, then by clicking the `back` button it will allow you to select the account.
- Otherwise, it disappears.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={myclientid}&scope=User.Read+Calendars.ReadWrite+offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri={my_redirect_url}&state=1234
```

[image]

When I clicked the **`back`** button, ***it redirected me to the account selection page***:

[image]

Now in the **Requested permissions page**:

[image]

When you click the **`cancel`** button, it will redirect to your redirect page and throw an error:

*AADSTS65004 User declined to consent to access the app.*

[image]

*This is the default sign in, and it cannot be modified you can instead customize the sign in page.*

You can **customize the sign in page of Microsoft Entra** by referring this MsDoc:

[Add company branding to your organization's sign-in page - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/how-to-customize-branding)